# Compare Discrete Fourier Transform for multiple signals

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, fourier

I have heart rate data from a wearable sensor (no ECG). I want to perform Discrete Fourier Transform to see if some patterns are present. I have over 200 signals, as each individual has heart rate measurements for multiple days. How can I analyze these signals? And is it also to compare population group A with group B?

Comment: Some individuals also have some missing data, should I just interpolate?